# $\nabla\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-y_{i})^{2}=(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})\in\mathscr{R}^{2n}?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

On page 116 of **Advanced Calculus of Several variables**, by C.H. Edwards, *Example 10* discusses finding the local minimum of the function 
$$f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-y_{i})^{2}$$
subject to the constraints $g(\mathbf{x})=0$ and $h(\mathbf{y})=0$.  As part of the example Edwards presents the result
$$\nabla f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})\in\mathscr{R}^{2n}.$$
Which seems to be missing a factor of 2.  Should the result not be
$$\nabla f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=2(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})?$$

Comment: Yes, it should. Hint for the future: put at least SOME words in your title so that people can click on it and get to the question.

Comment: @JohnHughes I ran out of characters in the title.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Sigh...in that case, I guess your title was perfect. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *yes*, there is an error in the book.